# Using mailx command for sending mail with attachment and messagebody in UNIX

Tags: email, unix, attachment, mailx

i have been trying to send an email from my script which is generating an excel and then zipping it. i want to send this zipped file as an attachment along with a message body, but no success.
i have been using the below code:
1) uuencode inputFileName OutputFileName | mailx -s "Report" abc@gmail.com -- -f abc@gmail.com

this commandline is successfully sending my attachment

2) uuencode inputFileName OutputFileName | mailx -s "Report" abc@gmail.com -- -f abc@gmail.com < MessageBody.txt

with this commandline, i am trying to send the same attachment with mail body fetched from external file MessageBody.txt, but it is then sending the mail only with mail body, and NO attachment.

Answer (score 0):

You are giving two different sources for stdin. At the beginning of the line you are taking stdin from stdout of uuencode but at the end of the line you are taking stdin from the file MessageBody.txt.

Instead you could try the following:

`uuencode inputFileName OutputFileName | cat - MessageBody.txt | mailx -s "Report" abc@gmail.com -- -f abc@gmail.com`

regards Henrik

Comment: this commandline is again sending out the mail with body, but without the attachment :(

Comment: Are you really sure that you didn't get the uuencoded data in the mail? If so, please double check that you wrote `cat - MessageBody.txt` which is supposed to merge the uuencoded data from stdin (-) with the contents of the file MessageBody.txt.